# Data inserted to Excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net

I did application using vb .net and when I using application on my PC everything work OK but once I copy application to another PC it's not working correctly.

The problem is data from application are saved in Excel file. In Excel file I got sheet where formula SUM data using criteria.

When I open Excel file on my pc data in this workbook are automatic updated. Once I open file on another PC i have to chose cell with formula edit and press enter then data are updated.

This a code which I use to insert data to Excel:

```
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=EXCEL_DATA\2SV REARS RFT.xlsx;Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""

    'Create an INSERT INTO SQL statement
    Dim insertStatement As String = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([Week], [Date], [Shift], [Frame Type], [Quantity], [Problem], [Weld Number], [Welder]) VALUES ('" + NOWEEK.Text + "','" + datee.Text + "','" + CHOSESHIFT.Text + "'," + FRAMETYPE.Text + "," + QUANTITY.Text + ",'" + PROBLEM.Text + "','" + WELDNUMBER.Text + "','" + WELDERNAME.Text + "')"
    'Create a connection object to connect to the Excel Workbook
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    'Create a command object that will execute the insert statement
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(insertStatement, connection)
    'Open the connection, execute the statement and close the connection
    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
    'Dispose of the connection and command objects
    connection.Dispose()
    command.Dispose()
    'Call the RefreshData routine so that you can see that data was indeed added.`enter code here`
```

This is formula in Excel which I use to sum data:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!E2:E4987,Sheet1!B2:B4987,Sheet4!B2,Sheet1!C2:C4987,"RED",Sheet1!D2:D4987,40%)
```

What I found that once data are inserted to Excel data were there are numbers excel asking me to convert to number.

Comment: It's behaving differently from the old to the new?  Which column are you being questioned on "convert to number"?

Comment: Both the PC running same version of office. Its asking me to convert date, frame and quantity .